# sys_call_table in linux kernel 2.6.18

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to set the sys exit call to a variable by

```
extern void *sys_call_table[];
real_sys_exit = sys_call_table[__NR_exit]
```

however, when I try to make, the console gives me the error

```
error: ‘__NR_exit’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Any tips would be appreciated :) Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are in kernel 2.6.x , sys_call_table isnt exported any more.
If you want to avoid the compilation error try this include

```
#include<linux/unistd.h>
```

however, It will not work. So the work around to "play" with the sys_call_table is to find the address of sys_call_table in SystemXXXX.map (located at /boot) with this command:

```
grep sys_call System.map-2.6.X -i
```

this will give the addres, then this code should allow you to modify the table:

```
unsigned long *sys_call_table; 
sys_call_table = (unsigned long *) simple_strtoul("0xc0318500",NULL,16); 


original_mkdir = sys_call_table[__NR_mkdir];
sys_call_table[__NR_mkdir] = mkdir_modificado;
```

Hope it works for you, I have just tested it under kernel 2.6.24, so should work for 2.6.18

also check here, Its a very good 
http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Network_Security_Tools/Modifying_and_Hacking_Security_Tools/Fun_with_Linux_Kernel_Modules

Comment: ... why are you using `strtoul` on a static value? Why not just use a literal `0xc0318500`? Also, this will fail on a relocatable kernel.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't included the file syscall.h, you should do that ahead of the reference to __NR_exit.  For example,

```
#include <syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", __NR_exit);
    return 0;
}
```

which returns:

```
$ cc t.c
$ ./a.out 
60
```

Some other observations:

1. If you've already included the file, the usual reasons `__NR_exit` wouldn't be defined are that the definition was being ignored due to conditional compilation (`#ifdef` or `#ifndef` at work somewhere) or because it's being removed elsewhere through a `#undef`.
2. If you're writing the code for kernel space, you have a completely different set of headers to use.  LXR (http://lxr.linux.no/linux) searchable, browsable archive of the kernel source is a helpful resource.

Comment: i have, and actually for some reason its actually linux/syscalls.h in this kernel version... :( maybe i got that wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the unhelpful answer.  I have to guess a lot about your compilation environment to answer the question.  E.g., I still don't know: what version of the linux kernel, what compiler version, compiler flags, whether the code is for cross-compiling, and whether you're trying to compile a kernel module or something for user-space. Can you provide any other information about your project?

Comment: Its linux kernel 2.6.18
Compiling with Makefile (gcc dunno what version)
obj-m += file.c
Making a kernel module to intercept syscalls.
I looked at the lxr, and it listed a bunch of syscall.h for my linux version, but its a patched kernel, so I may just need to ask my professor.
I tried a few of the headers from the lxr, and they were either missing, for the wrong architecture, or just didn't work.